# Relationship between singular values, traces and Hermitian conjugate

Tags: matrices, lie-algebras, operator-theory, traces, singular-values

I am working on a following problem in my free time (which is a simplified version of a problem described here - [arxiv.org/abs/0711.2613](https://arxiv.org/abs/0711.2613)):

> Let $A$, $B$ be zero-trace $4 \times 4$ matrices that meet following condition $\textit{Tr}(A^{\dagger}A) + \textit{Tr}(B^{\dagger}B)=\frac{1}{4}$. Show that
> $$
> \sigma_1^2(A+B) + \sigma_2^2(A+B) \leq \frac{1}{2} 
> $$
> or equivalently
> $$
> [\sigma_1(A)+\sigma_1(B)]^2 + [\sigma_1(A)+\sigma_2(B)]^2\geq \frac{1}{2}
> $$
> where $A^{\dagger}$ is a [Hermitian conjugate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermitian_adjoint) of matrix $A$ and $\sigma_i(A)$ is i-th largest [singular value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value) of matrix $A$

I tried attacking it with algebraic operations and identities I could find relating trace, singular values and other properties of a matrix, but I am stuck. I am working on this in my free time, so I decided that I can try to learn techniques from a specific area of mathematics that would bring me closer to solving this problem.

**What area of mathematics or specific tools would you recommend for tacking such problem?**

or

**What area of mathematics study or leverage relationship between traces and singular values?**

From googling and reading I found following candidates:

- simple Lie algebras - as matrices are traceless
- compact operators - as we are dealing with singular values
- Ky Fan norms - as we are dealing with sums of singular values (and sum of squares)
- ???

Comment: Most likely you won't need anything fancy for this kind of problem, you just need to know the definitions, and obviously some prior experience tends to help.

Comment: Your "equivalent" formulation (with the obvious typo corrected: $\le$ instead of $\ge$) is not really equivalent, rather it is a stronger inequality that implies the first one.

Comment: This problem seems to be equivalent to the one from https://arxiv.org/abs/0711.2613, and I assume that's where the author got it from. This is a hard question that has been open in this formulation for 13 years, and for about 25 years total. I think that MathOverflow typically frowns upon "how to solve this open problem?" questions.

Comment: @NathanielJohnston: This is a good find and I think you must be right on the origin of the question (but maybe the OP can clarify?). But then there's another mistake in the "translation": The singular values of $X=A\otimes 1+1\otimes B$ are not those of $A+B$; what is true is that the spectrum of $X$ is the sum of the spectra of $A,B$.

Comment: You are both correct. This is a simplified version of a problem mentioned in arxiv.org/abs/0711.2613.